# Freeing structs correctly

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I'm trying to free a struct and am having trouble with it. What I'm programming is kind of an n-ary tree or a virtual file system. I have 2 different structs (one for folders and one for files) and an array for each struct where every element is stored. The structs have a member ID and I've made so I can get a file/folder by using Folders[ID], which will return the struct with that ID. The problem I have is deleting / freeing them. First of all, if it is a folder that will be deleted, it will check recursively for children files and folders and delete these first. For some reason, I just can't get the free() to work, no matter what I try.

My Folder struct:

```
typedef struct {
    FolderID selfID;
    FolderID parentID;

    /* Other members are not important */
} FolderInfo;
```

My array:

```
FolderInfo Folders[MAX_FOLDERS];
```

How the FolderInfo structs are added to the array (In my new_folder function):

```c
/* ... */
FolderInfo *this = malloc(sizeof (FolderInfo));
/* ... */
ID++;
Folders[ID] = *this;
/* ... */
```

The delete function:

```
int32_t delete_folder(FolderID ID) {
    if(FolderIsEmpty(ID) == 1) {
        return -1; /* Error */
    }

    /* Check for children and delete them recursively */

    /* ... */

    free(Folders[ID]);
    return 0;
}
```

Everytime I create a new file/folder, it is added to the file/folder array under the index *ID*, so Folders[ID] should get the struct with that ID. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know the `free` isn't working?

Comment: `Folders[ID]` is not a pointer. It's a struct. You can't pass it to `free()`. It's a member of `Folders`, so when `Folders` is deallocated (at the end of its scope if it's a local variable or when the program exits if it's a global), it will be deallocated automatically. And from what I can tell, the whole dynamic allocation procedure is entirely useless in your code, since you are not relying on the structs being allocated dynamically. However, you are leaking memory because you are losing the pointer to the `malloc()`ated (original, temporary) struct.

Comment: As you say, `Folders[]` is a struct array that already has memory allocated. So why are you also dynamically allocating more?

Comment: Change `FolderInfo Folders[MAX_FOLDERS]` to `FolderInfo* Folders[MAX_FOLDERS]` and `Folders[ID] = *this` to `Folders[ID] = this`. Of course, you can simply refrain from using `malloc` and `free` to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
FolderInfo Folders[MAX_FOLDERS]
```

to

```
 FolderInfo* Folders[MAX_FOLDERS]
```

and

```
Folders[ID] = *this
```

to

```
 Folders[ID] = this.
```

Of course, you can simply refrain from using malloc and free to begin with.